# The automatic password input by expect does not work for mount remote machine to my local folder

Tags: bash, expect

This is my code :

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
set timeout 10
spawn bash -c "sshfs XXX@remote_computer:/raidc/users/XXX LocalDirectory/"
expect "XXX@remote_computer's password: "
send "mypasswd\r"
interact
expect eof
```

Here I want to automatically input my password to my LocalDirectory/. Though there is no error message, after running the script above, I cannot find the mounted stuff in LocalDirectory/. What should I do?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

In your expect command you have entered the whole output, you could use a wildcard if you wanted to,

`expect "*password?\r"`

The interact command an example i found in an article,

`interact ++ return`

After you type the password type ++ and the control will return from the keyboard to the script.

If you script does not have this, the control may not be given beck to the script and the timeout could be ending the script after,

more information from the following article, https://likegeeks.com/expect-command/amp